Hyperlink target in MS Edge sidebar
Is there way to open a hyperlink in MS Edge sidebar like target to open hyperlink in new tab like below.
<a href=http://www.austincc.edu/ target="_blank">Visit ACC!</a>

In this case target="_blank"  open a hyperlink in new tab. Like that is there any way to open a link in sidebar in MS-Edge

Great question; I came looking for the same answer. I was hoping something documented like target="_MSsidebar" would be the answer.

The current Edge browser may not directly support specifying how to open links in the sidebar.
The target attribute of the  tag specifies how the link target is opened, including:
_self: Open in the current window/tab (default).
_blank: Open in a new window/tab.
_parent: Open in the parent frame.
_top: Open in the entire window, replacing all frames.
However, it does not include the function of opening hyperlinks in the sidebar of Microsoft Edge.
